# How to design a Javascript library API with many callbacks?

Tags: javascript, api, callback, coffeescript

I am writing a Javascript library (in Coffeescript) that is a thin layer over a Comet implementation (CometD) that communicates with a server. There are basically two types of things that happen:

- Some client-side Javascript code calls `library.someAction()` and the action is sent to the server;
- Some event happens asynchronously and `library` needs to notify the client-side code of this event.

Here's the code for my current implementation:

https://github.com/HarvardEconCS/TurkServer/blob/master/turkserver-js-client/src/tsclient.coffee

Same code translated to Javascript: http://pastebin.com/w4ABf1vd

**For the client-initiated actions**, there is a function in the library for each type of action. For example, sometimes the client needs to send the results of a quiz to the server, so there is this corresponding function:

```
  @sendQuizResults: (correct, total) =>
    @channelSend "/service/user",
      status: Codec.quizResults
      correct: correct
      total: total
```

**For the server-initiated events**, the client-side code needs to register a callback for each type of event, so there are a whole pile of callbacks lying around and functions to set each of them. Namely, there are a huge bunch of the following:

```
  @requestUsername_cb = undefined

  @RequestUsername: (callback) ->
    @requestUsername_cb = callback
```

In the above example, if a `RequestUsername` event is triggered, the client calls the `requestUsername_cb()` if it exists.

This seems like it's starting to become a mess, so I was wondering if there are any good practices for creating a library like this, and organizing all the events and actions in a reasonable way. CS basically wraps all the functions above into a closure so they can be used as a JS object.

I have to admit I'm one of those Javascript users that kind of just started using the language, and then jumped into Coffeescript for various reasons. If there's something I don't understand well about Javascript, then I would be happy to be enlightened; however, I don't want this to go off topic/turn into a flame war about CS vs JS or something else. Please limit your answers to best practices for this type of API in general.

Comment: the problem is not flame war , the issue is people who know javascript very well might not answer you because they cant read coffee-script code. So your question might appeal to far less programmers than if you were using javascript directly. Unless it is coffeescript related , i never write js questions in cs because of this. Imagine a HTML related question written in HAML ...

Comment: That's fine, I will take answers in Javascript :)

Comment: If people cant read coffeescript they will not answer you in javascript.

Comment: Ok, I added a javascript version of the code.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you want is some node-style events; however, how you design and structure an API is generally up to you.

Node.js handles events with EventEmitter classes. These classes have certain events(just defined as strings), and a set of listeners(these are just functions) for each event. These events are fired by method `emit`, and are attached to by method `on`. You just need to define something to hook into. Let's use EventEmitter to define one such class.

```
{ EventEmitter } = require 'events'

class TurkEmitter extends EventEmitter

module.exports = new TurkEmitter
```

The developer would use this class like so:

```
TurkEmitter = require 'TurkEmitter' # Whatever path

TurkEmitter.on 'connect', (event) ->
    doSomething(with: event)
```

They just hooked into TurkEmitter's `'connect'` event, and their function will be called any time that event is fired. The developer can attach multiple listeners to that event, remove listeners, etc.

Somewhere in your code, you fire this event with `emit`:

```
TurkEmitter.emit 'connect', { some: 'object here' } # Any object that the developer will use
```

It seems as if there's a piece of code written that will run on the client, and a piece that will run on the server. In that case, you'll want to write a simple port of EventEmitter for the client side.

Comment: `EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter` is better written as `{EventEmitter} = require 'events'`.

Comment: The server side code is already written. This is all going to be on the client side. Are there any node or other libraries that I can just include in my client-side JS for this type of functionality?

Comment: You can use EventEmitter2. Here's a simple js file you can download and include(works both with node and the browser): https://github.com/hij1nx/EventEmitter2/blob/master/lib/eventemitter2.js